# I want to read number of pages of a pdf file in React JS and I am using react-pdf and pdfjs-dist. I am getting this error... Can someone please guide?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-pdf, pdfjs-dist

node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js 1198:17
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1198:17)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  |         }
  |         class PDFDocumentLoadingTask {

> ```
>       static #docId = 0;
> ```

|           constructor() {
|             this._capability = (0, _util.createPromiseCapability)();

I get this error when I import this library
import { Document, Page } from "react-pdf/dist/esm/entry.webpack";

Can someone please guide how to solve this?

Comment: You have a babel config? Sounds like react-pdf ships untranspiled typescript